# Python "is not None" returning None

Tags: python, null, iteration

I'm iterating through a JSON object that has null for some of its values. I'm trying to store those values in another object, and replace null with an empty string. However it seems "is not None" is returning "None". resource[key] should either be a string, or an empty string, but it's printing "None"

```
def sanitize_resource(self, *args):
    resource = {}
    for key, value in args[0].iteritems():
        resource[key] = str(value) if value is not None else ''
        print resource[key]
    return resource
```

Example of args[0]

```
{"Resource Name":"Alexander","Contact Name":null,"Contact Email":null,"Primary Phone":"(828) 632","Primary Phone Ext":null,"Alternate Phone":null,"Alternate Phone Ext":null,"TTY":null,"Website URL":"http://url.org/locations/alexander/","Website Tiny URL":null,"Website Name":null,"Email":"live@url.org","Street Address":"260 Road","Street Address 2":null,"City":"Taylor","State":"FC","Postal Code":12345,"Description":null,"Category":null,"Tags":null,"Notes":null,"Services":null,"Longitude":null,"Latitude":null,"Thumbnail":null}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a `None` object. You have the *string* `"None"`.

You can detect the difference by using `repr()` rather than printing the objects out straight:

```
print repr(value)
```

A string will be printed with the quotes.

Demo:

```
>>> value = None
>>> print repr(value)
None
>>> str(value) if value is not None else ''
''
>>> value = "None"
>>> print repr(value)
'None'
>>> str(value) if value is not None else ''
'None'
```

Comment: if value is not 'None' else '' still gives me None.
Example output of repr(value):
u'98001'
None

Comment: @user1637231 No. `if is not None and value != 'None'` would be appropriate. You don't compare strings with `is`...

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately resource[key] = str(value) if value is not None and value != 'None' else '' is still None

Comment: @user1637231; if you also want to replace `value` with `''` if it is `"None"`, use *equality* testing, not identity testing. `if value is not None and value != 'None'`. You could also just use `value not in ('None', None)` in this case.

Comment: @user1637231: without test data this discussion is pointless however. I have shown you how Python will operate if `value` is bound to the `None` singleton object. Can you show us a `repr()` output of an object that behaves differently? Is there whitespace involved, for example?

Comment: . yes, I have the repr(value) output in my first comment. It outputs None with no quotes, the other values look like this u'whatever string value'

Comment: @user1637231: your sample data in the question does **not** exhibit the behaviour you claim to see: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/46bb32a43ede6c5ac63f

Comment: I suppose that makes sense though. I was printing str(value) when I wanted resource[key]. Thanks again

Comment: @user1637231: note that I used `repr(value)` and `repr(str(value) if value is not None else '')` to show what the expression output produces.